# Is it normal that the RPM jumps to 800 from 600 when I switch on the AC in my Toyota yaris automatic 2015

Tags: rpm

I own a Toyota yaris 2015 AUTOMATIC. normal RPM is 600 but when I turn the AC on the rpm jumps to 800.is it normal, is there any issue

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is normal.

The ac requires some 10 to 12 bhp from the engine and the ecu is allowing for that energy demand by increasing the idle speed so it will not stall.

Comment: Tip - turn off the a/c when climbing mountains, especially in a low-powered car.